# Difference between s3cmd, boto and AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, s3cmd, aws-cli

I am thinking about redeploying my static website to Amazon S3. I need to automate the deployment so I was looking for an API for such tasks. I'm a bit confused over the different options.

**Question**: What is the difference between s3cmd, the Python library boto and AWS CLI?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) and [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) are both command line tools.  They're well suited if you want to script your deployment through shell scripting (e.g. bash).

AWS CLI gives you simple file-copying abilities through the "s3" command, which should be enough to deploy a static website to an S3 bucket. It also has some small advantages such as being pre-installed on Amazon Linux, if that was where you were working from (it's also [easily installable through `pip`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-with-pip)).

One AWS CLI command that may be appropriate to sync a local directory to an S3 bucket:

```
$ aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket
```

Full documentation on this command:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

*Edit: As mentioned by @simon-buchan in a comment, the `aws s3api` command gives you access to the complete S3 API, but its interface is more "raw".*

s3cmd supports everything AWS CLI does, plus adds some more extended functionality on top, although I'm not sure you would require any of it for your purposes.  You can see all its commands here:
http://s3tools.org/usage

Installation of s3cmd may be a bit more involved because it doesn't seem to be packages for it in any distros main repos.

[boto](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/) is a Python library, and in fact the official AWS Python SDK.  The AWS CLI, also being written in Python, actually uses part of the boto library ([botocore](http://botocore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)).  It would be well suited only if you were writing your deployment scripts in Python.  There are official SDKs for other popular languages (Java, PHP, etc.) should you prefer:
http://aws.amazon.com/tools/

The rawest form of access to S3 is through AWS's REST API.  Everything else is built upon it at some point.  If you feel adventurous, here's the S3 REST API documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html

Comment: Are there any benchmarks comparing data transfer rates using s3cmd to awscli?

Comment: There are `s3cmd` official packages for Ubuntu: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/s3cmd

Comment: Also check out s4cmd. While it doesn't have all the features of s3cmd, its performance is definitely better over high-bandwidth connections (e.g. on EC2), since it multithreads the connections. https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd

Comment: "AWS CLI gives you only the basic commands" isn't true, `aws s3 *` is just the simplified interface, the full REST API is available under `aws s3api *`

Comment: It's not quite true s3cmd gives you everything aws-cli does. In particular, it's slower as it [does not have parallel workers/connections](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/2). (s4cmd has this too.)

Comment: boto gives you ALL the aws service APIs.  So if you need access to cognito, cloudwatch, ec2 management, or any of the long list of services, you either need to find a package for each one, or use boto for all.  If you are going to be using more than a couple of services, it may make sense to use boto, as you'll have a common api style across all of them.

Comment: @jlevy So s3cmd inlucdes all of functions in 'aws *' or not?