# intermittent Unable to locate credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

We are using the following version of Boto to write to SQS -

- boto3==1.7.16
- botocore==1.10.16

The code is running successfully in production environment, but once in a while we see the following intermittent error -

`NoCredentialsError` Unable to locate credentials.

The following is the stack trace -

```
File "botocore/client.py", line 317, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "botocore/client.py", line 602, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
File "botocore/endpoint.py", line 143, in make_request
  return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
File "botocore/endpoint.py", line 168, in _send_request
  request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
File "botocore/endpoint.py", line 152, in create_request
  operation_name=operation_model.name)
File "botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
  return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
File "botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
  response = handler(**kwargs)
File "botocore/signers.py", line 90, in handler
  return self.sign(operation_name, request)
File "botocore/signers.py", line 154, in sign
  auth.add_auth(request)
File "botocore/auth.py", line 352, in add_auth
  raise NoCredentialsError
```

We have the following api which can be called from multiple threads -

```
    def client(self):
        if not self._client:
            self._client = boto3.client('sqs', self.region)
        return self._client
```

Comment: How are you supplying the credentials? Is it running on an Amazon EC2 instance with a role assigned, or is it coming through a `.aws/credentials` file? If this is intermittent, then it could be a network error, where you just have to try again.

Comment: Hi John, 

The credentials are coming from .aws/credentials

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? We're having similar issue using boto3 from multiple threads.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not. To solve this problem we introduced retires considering its an intermittent issue.

Answer (score 0):

I intermittently see this error from a cron job that runs `aws cloudwatch put-metric-data`. (Relevance: ["The AWS CLI, also being written in Python, actually uses part of the boto library (botocore)."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html))

> Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

The cron job has run every five minutes for several years on dozens of servers that use [IAM roles for Amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326408/difference-between-s3cmd-boto-and-aws-cli) and I get an email for this error about once a week. Back of napkin calculations put it at about a 0.00007% failure rate across all of my servers.

> An application on the instance retrieves the security credentials provided by the role from the instance metadata item iam/security-credentials/role-name. The application is granted the permissions for the actions and resources that you've defined for the role through the security credentials associated with the role. These security credentials are temporary and we rotate them automatically. We make new credentials available at least five minutes before the expiration of the old credentials.

My working theory is that a network failure (especially on cheap legacy t2.micro servers) causes the credential download to fail, which is then surfaced as the authentication error.

This hasn't been enough of a disruption for me to dig into it further, but perhaps someone else is annoyed enough to prove or disprove my theory.

Answer (score -2):

This issue is mainly caused because Boto3 cannot identify the proper credentials for AWS. There are [different ways](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html) to solve this problem. Before everything, try the following step.

**STEP 1**: Specify the ACCESS_ID and ACCESS_KEY manually. Do not directly insert these values to the code for security reasons. If this works, then you are sure that Boto is finding it difficult to find access credentials.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client(
    'sqs',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
)
```

---

**Other Option:** open the AWS credentials file. `~/.aws/credentials`. Add the profile name as default and run the program.

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=YYYYYYYYYYY
```

If you prefer to have a different profile name, you can specify this in the Boto session.

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=your_profile_name)
```

Or you can also change the `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` environment variable name to "your_profile_name"

---

**Other Option:** You can set up the credentials via the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/). Install AWS CLI via PIP.

```
pip install awscli
```

Next, configure the credentials and other information via the following command.

```
aws configure
```

Hope this helps.